How do I import a Nanobind Module into a Python script?
I have created a C++ file and used Nanobind to create a module. When I start a Python shell from the build directory I am able to import the module and run the function as normal, however I have not been able to import the module to a Python file.
This is my current import statement which I found from this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-from-different-directory/
import return_thermal_data

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/get_thermal_values/build')

However I get the error "Unable to import 'return_thermal_data'"
I have also attempted to place the Python file directly in the build folder but this has not worked either.
Here is the nanobind_add_module statement from CMakeLists.txt
nanobind_add_module(return_thermal_data return_thermal_data.cpp)

And here is the NB_MODULE statement in the CSS
NB_MODULE(return_thermal_data, m) {
m.def("subscribe_to_topic", &subscribeToTopic, "Subscribe to the data topic");}

As far as I can tell the Nanobind docs only demo using modules via the Python shell. Is it possible to use them with Pythons scripts, or is there another tools I should use to achieve this?

Does your actual code modify sys.path before importing the module? If not, there's your problem.
